# Insert an image in <p: menubar>

Tags: xml, primefaces, xhtml

****hello friends I have a little problem with an imegen that I want to insert at the beginning of a menubar but the submenu that is at the same time is included in the image, and try with many methods but I can not solve this could help me please?
I am sharing the code of the bar I am handling**
[estrong textnter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxHh4.png)**

```html
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">


    <h:form>
        
        <p:menubar  style="background: #333; width: 100%;">
            <p:menuitem>
                <h:graphicImage value="/imgs/Slidenew1.png" style="margin-left: 10px; position: fixed;" width="50px" height="70px"></h:graphicImage>
            </p:menuitem>
<!--            <p:menuitem><img src="#{request.contextPath}/imgs/Slidenew1.png" style="margin-left: 10px; position: fixed;" width="50px" height="70px"></img></p:menuitem>-->
            <p:submenu label="SIANSA" icon="ui-icon-person" style="width: 110px; color: #fff;">
                <p:menuitem value="Perfil" url="#" icon="ui-icon-person" style="color: black;"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Registro de Usuarios" action="#{buttonView.registroUsuarios}" icon="ui-icon-plusthick" style="color: black;" ajax="false"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Salir" action="#{buttonView.buttonExit}" style="color: black;" icon="ui-icon-closethick" ajax="false"></p:menuitem>
            </p:submenu>          
            <p:menuitem value="Segmento Estilos" action="#{buttonView.segmentoEstilos}" style="color: white;" ajax="false"></p:menuitem>
            <p:menuitem value="Segmento Clases" style="color: white;"></p:menuitem>
            <p:submenu label="Consultas" icon="ui-icon-help" style="width: 125px; color: #CCCCCC;">
                <p:menuitem value="General" url="#" style="color: black;"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Por Estilos" url="#" style="color: black;"></p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Por Clases" url="#" style="color: black;"></p:menuitem>
            </p:submenu>
            <p:menuitem value="Home" action="#{buttonView.buttonAction}" icon="ui-icon-home" style="color: whitesmoke; float: right;" ajax="false" ></p:menuitem>
        </p:menubar> 
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Edit your title.

Comment: **Why are you screaming at me in bold?!?!?!?!** and this is does not look like java, so please remove that tag

Comment: please try to use `icon="ui-icon-home"` instead of graphicImage  in menuitem ?!?

Comment: I do not understand how you could explain or an example please